NCBI Virus experimentally determined proteins
I am trying to find neuraminidase sequences from influenza virus to work with (as many as possible if not ideally everything available) and I have been using NCBI Virus for this (this is my search query).
How can I eliminate the neuraminidase sequences that are only theoretically determined? I need only protein level data, experimental evidence (i.e. "Experimental evidence at protein level" according to this). When using uniprot to look for neuraminidase (uniprot.org/uniprotkb?query=neuraminidase) i can filter by "protein existence" and one of the options is "protein level", but I couldn't identify a filter in NCBI Virus for this.
Thank you!

Just switch to NCBI and use the online Blast if the sequences sought are less than ~50K (I forget the upper limit and I think it's been lowered). Otherwise perform a local Blast. Generally, theoretical sequences are removed from NBCI and if present will be clearly tagged.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but the "protein level" stuff has very little relationship to the sequences themselves- it's more an annotation confidence thing. If you really restricted to that level, you might find that you have only 5-10 NA sequences total, because that's the number that have had X-ray structures solved (or whatever). Basically no one is isolating / directly detecting NA protein from their samples when they register NA sequences, because it's immensely laborious to do so. I think that the assumption is that if it's a flu virus and has an NA sequence, that's good enough.
